# Interface a C++ algorithm in Mobile environment

Tags: android, c++, iphone, android-ndk

I want to make an interface for a C++ complicated algorithm on a tablet environment, the idea of a server running the C++ code isn't applicable.

Can I embed my C++ algorithm in NDK application (for android, can I do the same for iOS?) and make the interface with Android SDK, and then use the NDK app (maybe as a function) in my SDK android app?? is this scenario possible and how hard it's?

I'd prefer the most a solution involving cordova and hybrid approaches.

If there is a simpler approach I'd appreciate any idea.

Comment: The answer is "yes, you can do this". Unfortunately your entire question premise is one which is not appropriate at Stack Overflow as it requires conversation. Stack Overflow is strictly oriented towards questions with precise answers, not suggestions on the myriad ways a problem can be solved. That is... implement your preferred approach, and if you run into trouble, feel free to post a question including the relevant code in order to solicit help on your concrete problem.

Comment: Thank you, can you provide me with a good forum for discussion like this?

Comment: I'm not aware of one unfortunately, but you might check on other stack exchange sites - there's a list of the more popular ones at the bottom of this page. I'm just not certain what their expectations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to port some code to Android. I do not know if you code has been ever built under Android.

Anyway, first of all you have to locate and manage to build the `hello-jni` example in the Android NDK. I have it in `android-ndk-r9d/samples/hello-jni`. After that, you may start to add functions to that project. Forwarding data between Java and C++ is... well... error-prone.

Android comes with two build systems, the old one is **ant**-based, the new one is **gradle**. In addition, some guys manage to use 3rd-party build systems for Android.

If your project has never been built under Android, you will have to port it. If it has Windows/Linux/Mac builds, start from a Linux or a Mac one (in the latter case please note that "darwin" contains "win", this may cause bugs in your build script.) You will likely have to borrow some standard functions from where you can find them. In addition, a while ago Android did not support `std::string` at all...

If your project *has* been built under Android, you will have to manage to build it yourself and then use the binaries. Alternatively, you might prefer to just use the existing binaries (this will require less effort) and just not care about bugs.

One more possible approach is to find the project that both uses your preferred build system and has an Android build, build that project for Android and remove the contents, thus obtaining an empty project that is built with your build system of choice. I did no do this and I suppose it will not be as easy as it sounds now. (But you will have a chance to become an expert in that build system.) ***UPD*** This section applies mostly to projects that come with a 3rd-party build system. Usually such exotic build systems have some specific features, and one needs these features to build successfully. The general rule is that beyond some level of complexity all working systems are modifications of other working systems (and are never created from scratch). (Example: programmers add functionality gradually and testing is done after each addition; they just cannot write all and then test all.) So in the case of a 3rd-party build system it may be reasonable to take some working project using that 3rd-party build system, get the build system working and replace the project source.

In general what you want is possible for both Android and iOS, but there is no general-case solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response,but I didn't exactly understand what you mean by use your preferred build system, you mean build system for android NDK?can you please explain ur last suggestion in further details,(the C++ algorithm is built on win, I asked this question so we won't need to re-program it in another language, If I understood correctly, you suggested to adjust the code so we can compile it for android right? and the last thing, can we wrap both the NDK and SDK application in the same package so they can be downloaded as one application?)

Comment: and sorry for not being familiar with some technical terms, I'm not much of an expert but I'm trying to be with the help of people like you, I just need guidance, I'm not searching for easy answers.

Comment: Unless your project is a command-line utility, the .apk will contain the .so libraries -- the `libs/` subdirectory may contain subdirectories `armeabi`,  `armeabi-v7a`,  `mips`, `x86` for different platforms, you most likely need only `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`. Note that Android can use `armeabi` instead of  `armeabi-v7a`, but cannot combine libraries from these two directories, so if you have one library pre-built for armeabi and cannot build it for armeabi-v7a, there's no use to compile for armeabi-v7a at all, that one library will be missing.

Comment: Android comes with two build systems, the old one is __ant__-based, the new one is __gradle__. In addition, some guys manage to use 3rd-party build systems for Android.

Comment: Yes, when you replace all winapi functions by their posix analogs preserving the functionality so that the program may execute on Linux/Android, this is called _porting_.